# is it possible to open a websocket in java without jetty, tomcat,...?

Tags: java, websocket

Is it possible to write a java aplication which acts as an websocket server, without any Servlet Engines like jetty, tomcat....?

If yes, which Frameworks are out there?
I came accross jWebSocket, but can't find any examples or in the javadoc, how I can open a simple websocket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jWebSocket for sure you can open a web socket and there are lot of examples for the same.

1) https://jwebsocket.org/about-jws/Press-Articles/cross-platform/real-time-cross-platform-communication-websockets

2) https://technology.amis.nl/2012/01/14/implementing-a-java-server-side-component-for-jwebsocket-server-for-websocket-interaction-with-web-clients/

Comment: can I talk to this websocket via the ordinary javscript websocket or do I have to use the jWebSocket.js implementation?

Comment: that you have to try and see for yourself. But most probably its required.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was confused because theres nothing in the code e.g which port the websocket listens to. Thats all in the config file, and now it is clear. Thanks for you resources